# How to connect SAP HANA Studio and PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hana

I am new to SAP HANA and I want to connect to a PostgreSQL Server. So what I did was opened the SAP HANA Studio and then clicked add a system and gave the hostname, username and password of the PostgreSQL database. But it did not work.

By this can we only connect to SAP HANA system? If so how to connect to PostgreSQL and access the data in Studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "did not work" is not a useful problem description. You should explain specifically what you did, how you did it, and exactly what happened, posting the text of any error messages you received and describing specifically any unexpected behavior. For example, "I entered my username and password in the box and clicked OK, but I got a message saying, 'Error E, Could not authenticate user due to a System Error 25 in Module Auth - UnrecognizedServerProtocolException' The application then returned me to the login box."

Answer (score 1):

SAP HANA Studio works only with SAP HANA - not with other DBMS.

Comment: As HANA Studio is essentially an Eclipse with some SAP plugins, I guess there _should_ be a way, shouldn't it?

Comment: You can of course add any other eclipse plugin to the same eclipse environment and if that plugin connects to Postgresql that's fine. But this doesn't give you any integration to Sap HANA or the other sap HANA studio plugins. So, to me that's not what you mean when you ask for a sap Hana studio connection to PostgreSQL.